# Appending a current date from a variable to a filename

Tags: bash, shell, rename, date

I'm trying to append the current date to the end of a file name like this:

```
TheFile.log.2012-02-11
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
set today = 'date +%Y'
mkdir -p The_Logs &
find . -name The_Logs -atime -1 -type d -exec mv \{} "The_Logs_+$today" \; &
```

However all I get is the name of the file, and it appends nothing.  How do I append a current date to a filename?

Comment: when you apppand date, make sure not to use `:` because then it will be read as a host in rsync and scp. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37143274/390066

Answer (score 105, accepted):

More than likely it is your use of `set`.  That will assign 'today', '=' and the output of the `date` program to positional parameters (aka command-line arguments).  You want to just use C shell (which you are tagging this as "bash", so likely not), you will want to use:

```
today=`date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S` # or whatever pattern you desire
```

Notice the lack of spaces around the equal sign.

You also do not want to use `&` at the end of your statements; which causes the shell to not wait for the command to finish.  Especially when one relies on the next.  The `find` command could fail because it is started before the `mkdir`.

Comment: Thanks for that mate, its working %100 fine now, Cheers for the heads-up & and mkdir

Answer (score 67):

### Bash script to inject a date into a filename:

**This bash code in file called `a.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash
today=`date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`;
filename="/home/el/myfile/$today.ponies"
echo $filename;
```

**When run, prints:**

```
eric@dev ~ $ chmod +x a.sh

eric@dev ~ $ ./a.sh
/home/el/myfile/2014_08_11__15_55_25.ponies
```

**Explanation of the code:**

Interpret the script with the /bin/bash interpreter.  Make a new variable called today.  Execute the date command, passing in the Y, m, d, H, M, S flags to configure the output.  Place the result into the date variable.

Create a new variable called filename, surround the $today variable with the rest of the static filename text.  then echo the filename to screen.

**Cram it into a one-liner to increase lulz:**

```
echo "/home/el/myfile/`date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`.ponies"
```

Answer (score 9):

You seem to have mixed up several things.

`set today = 'date +%Y'` looks like tcsh syntax, but even in tcsh it assigns the string `date +%Y` to the variable `today`, it doesn't run the `date` command. As you're probably using bash or some other POSIX shell, the syntax of an assignment is `today=some_value` (with no spaces around the equal sign). To run the command and assign its output to the variable, use [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution):

```
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

(I've also completed the date specification). You can use backquotes instead of dollar-parentheses, but it's prone to being visually confused with forward quotes, and the rules for when you need quotes inside a backquoted command are pretty complex and implementation-dependent, so it's better not to stick to `$(…)` (which has the same effect with a saner syntax).

You used `&` at the end of several commands. That makes the command execute in the background, which is not wanted here. I suspect you meant `&&`, which means to execute the next command only if the first command succeeded.

```
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
mkdir -p The_Logs &&
find …
```

An alternative to using `&&` after each command is to start your script with `set -e`. This tells the shell to stop executing the script as soon as any command returns a nonzero status (except for commands in `if` conditions and a few other cases).

```
set -e
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
mkdir -p The_Logs
find …
```

Your `find` command is fine but probably doesn't do what you intend to do (though I don't know for sure what that is).

You're creating a directory with `mkdir` and then immediately traversing it with `find`. That won't be useful unless the directory already exists. Did you mean to create a directory for today's logs and move recent files from `The_Logs` to a directory called e.g. `The_Logs.2012-02-11`?

```
mkdir -p "The_Logs.$today"
find The_Logs -mtime -1 -exec mv {} "The_Logs.$today" \;
```

Or did you mean to rename today's log files to add the suffix `$today`? That requires calculating the different file name for each file to move.

```
find The_Logs -mtime -1 -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$0.$today"' {} \;
```

Note that I used `-mtime`, to move files based on their modification time, and not `-atime`, which is the time the file was last read (if your system keeps track of that — if it doesn't, the atime may be as far back as the mtime).

Answer (score 4):

You can rename file with time stamp appended to it

```
mv TheFile.log TheFile.log.`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
find . -name The_Logs -atime -1 -type d -exec mv {} "The_Logs_${today}" \; &
```

should work. Although, it seems like you are using csh and my solution of removing the + sign may not work for you but it won't hurt to try. Enclosing your variable in {} curly brackets, is always a good idea to prevent unexpected variable expansions.

Comment: Thanks mate, after adding your correction with the other answer, its working fine.