# Current time/date as a variable in BASH and stopping a program with a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, timestamps, real-time

I am trying to create a raspberry pi spy cam bug. 
I am trying to make it so the new file created for the various processes come up with

```
NOW=`date '+%F_%H:%M:%S'`;
```

which works fine.
but it requires an echo to update the time
`$NOW` is also in the `/home/pi/.bashrc` file
Same issue, does not update wo

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

I found *[on this forum here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57590/appending-a-current-date-from-a-variable-to-a-filename)* and it works:

```
#! /bin/bash

NOW=`date '+%F_%H:%M:%S'`;

filename="/home/pi/gets/$NOW.jpg"

raspistill -n -v -t 500 -o $NOW.jpg;

echo $filename;
```

I don't get how it works bc it's before o the output of raspistil and in quotes.

Thank you all in advance!!!

Comment: found the forum I lifted that code from, it's this one.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57590/appending-a-current-date-from-a-variable-to-a-filename
toward the bottom VVV

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you do

```
NOW=`date '+%F_%H:%M:%S'`
```

or, using more modern syntax,

```
NOW=$( date '+%F_%H:%M:%S' )
```

the variable `NOW` will be set to the output of the `date` command at the time when that line is executed.  If you do this in `~/.bashrc`, then `$NOW` will be a timestamp that tells you when you started the current interactive shell session.

You could also set the variable's value with

```
printf -v NOW '%(%F_%H:%M:%S)T' -1
```

if you're using `bash` release 4.2 or later.  This prints the timestamp directly into the variable without calling `date`.

In the script that you are showing, the variable `NOW` is being set when the script is run (this is what you want).

When the assignment

```
filename="/home/pi/gets/$NOW.jpg"
```

is carried out, the shell will expand the variable in the string.  It does this even though it is in double quotes.  *Single quotes* stops the shell from expanding embedded variables (this is *not* what you want in this case).

Note that you don't seem to actually use the `filename` variable in the call to `raspistill` though, so I'm not certain why you set its value, unless you just want it outputted by `echo` at the end.

In the rest of the code, you should double quote the `$NOW` variable expansion (and `$filename`). If you don't, and later change how you define `NOW` so that it includes spaces or wildcards (filename globbing patterns), the commands that use `$NOW` may fail to parse their command line properly.

Compare, e.g.,

```
string="hello * there"

printf 'the string is "%s"\n' $string
```

with

```
string="hello * there"

printf 'the string is "%s"\n' "$string"
```

---

Related things:

- About backticks in command substitutions: [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated)
- About quoting variable expansions: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) and [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: thank you for the info, I have been reading up on printf.
i compared the 2 lines, i do not get why the not doubled quoted listed the files in that directory. I get the substitutions, like truffles.

Comment: @RecklessLiberty That's the whole point of quoting the variable expansion. Without the quote, the * will perform a filename glob and be expanded to the names in the current directory.

Comment: that's weird, it did the hello and there too. do you know where I could read up on this? why did it go for the file names?

Comment: @RecklessLiberty An unquoted `*` expands to all names in the current directory.  If you had used `*.txt`, it would have expanded to the names that ended with `.txt`.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)  and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Comment: bc it's echo'd in plain text!!! wo the quotes each character will be interpreted. 
Got it, it clicked, that did it.
Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a few practical pointers:

1. Don't use characters such as `:` for naming files! Before using any non-alphanumeric character, ask yourself whether it could possibly mess up any future script or command line one-liner. Use a dash or underline instead, or just squish the elements together with no delimiter.
2. Since your question indicates that you are using `bash`, you should know that recent versions of that shell include a native version of date-spec output withing the shell's own `printf` command. Use it like so:

   ```
   printf "%(%F_%H%M%S)T"
   ```

   or

   ```
   NOW=$(printf "%(%F_%H%M%S)T")
   ```

   or even

   ```
   printf -v NOW "%(%F_%H%M%S)T"
   ```

   (which avoids forking an extra process)
3. The `bash` version of printing a date-spec has the additional advantage of two features not present otherwise: "-1 represents the current time, and -2 represents the time the shell was invoked. If no argument is specified, conversion behaves as if -1 had been given." For example,

   ```
   printf -v THEN "%(%F_%H%M%S)T" -2
   ```

Comment: That's a nice feature of Bash's `printf`, but I don't really feel convinced about your first point. Why would `:` (or non-alphanumeric characters in general) be bad in filenames?

Comment: @Kusalananda - What initially comes to mind are two cases: 1) hostnames: if you have a colon and it gets sucked up by a glob into a script for use with something like `rsync`, `scp`, or even `find`, it can end up crashing the script looking for a network hostname. 2) Lists of things, such a folders in your $PATH or in an `ldd` pathh list, use the colon as a delimiter.

Comment: @Kusalananda I answered (I think) a question on here a while ago where somebody couldn't extract an archive because the target filesystem didn't support `:` in filenames. That seems like a good reason to avoid them

Comment: All valid points under specific circumstances. But on the same premises, you could also say that you should adhere to Windows naming conventions _in case_ the files were to be transferred to such a system.

Comment: What if you do port to windows or happen to be accessing the files in an application that doesn't support the characters at a later date. You can prevent those situations from coming back and biting you by just sticking to best practices in the first place. Of course that is your choice to make either way, but I know how I would be working it.

Comment: Note that that `%T` format was copied from ksh93 / ast-open (where it's much more advanced as it allows a wide variety of date/time/offsets specifications, where bash only allows epoch seconds or -1, -2).

Answer (score 2):

Since Bash 5: if the number of seconds since epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00) satisfies your needs, you can get that timestamp from two predefined variables:

```
# Seconds since epoch
echo ${EPOCHSECONDS}

# Seconds with microsecond precision since epoch
echo ${EPOCHREALTIME}

# Microseconds since epoch
echo ${EPOCHREALTIME/./}

# Miliseconds since epoch
echo $(( ${EPOCHREALTIME/./} / 1000 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to have the time actually update while the script was running in bash to prevent stompage on files I was updating more than once (yes yes) and still have it simply be "assigned" to a variable.  Pretty sure this isn't an issue in Perl, but it's been a while.

user1404316's answer doesn't work for me with bash 4.2 on RHEL.

Here's how I solved this in bash 4.2:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(printf "%(%F_%H%M%S)T")
echo printf: ${now}
sleep 1
echo printf after 1: ${now}

# Tried backticks here too :(    
then="$(date +%s)"

# This is your now date
now() { date +%s; }

# This is how you use it    
filename="something.$(now)"

echo "now ${filename}"
filename="something.${then}"
echo "then ${filename}"
sleep 1
filename2="something.$(now)"
echo "now ${filename2}"
filename2="something.${then}"
echo "then ${filename2}"
```

and the output:

```
printf: 1969-12-31_190000
printf after 1: 1969-12-31_190000
now something.1588791459
then something.1588791459
now something.1588791460
then something.1588791459
```

Hope this helps someone :)

1. Have to give some credit to [user unknown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305624/how-to-declare-functions-as-variables) @ askubuntu.com as I did review that code while trying to find the right solution.

Comment: Why not `now() { printf '%(%F_%H%M%S)T' }`?