# Stopping a script process with a Control + C or something

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, audio, process-management

I am trying to make an AV bug raspberry pi for a class.

I am using sox to record sound. 
Which is working fine.

the issue is sox needs to be stopped by a control+C to stop and create the new file. If killall is sent from a different ssh session it will drop the other session and sox will not create the file.

**listen.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
NOW=$( date '+%F_%H:%M:%S' )

filename="/home/pi/gets/$NOW.wav"

sox -t alsa plughw:1  $NOW.wav;

sleep 6;

echo $filename
```

I have tried making a separate script for stopping it; pretty much

**killlisten.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 5;
ps | grep sox | kill 0;
```

Then run a

**superscript.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
./listen.sh;
./killlisten.sh;
```

Any advice on how to stop sox in a way that would still produce an output file would be great.  This will ideally be set to run at set times so avoiding human interaction is essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pipeline

```
ps -aux | grep sox | kill 0
```

will not do what you want to do.  This is because `kill` won't ever read the input from `grep` (the result from `grep` will also contain *a lot* of other things than just the PID of the `sox` process).

If you have `pkill`, just do

```
pkill sox
```

instead (use `pkill -INT sox` to send the same signal as <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> does).

If you change your startup script to

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$( date '+%F_%H:%M:%S' )

filename="/home/pi/gets/$NOW.wav"
sox -t alsa plughw:1  "$NOW.wav" & sox_pid="$!"

printf 'sox pid is %d\n' "$sox_pid"

wait

# Alternatively (instead of "wait", if you want to kill sox after six seconds):
# sleep 6 && kill "$sox_pid" 

echo "$filename"
```

You will get the PID of the `sox` process printed to the terminal and you could use that to do `kill pid` (with `pid` replaced by that number).

Using `&` ofte the `sox` invocation places it in the background.  The PID of that background task is automatically stored in `$!` and the code above assigns it to `sox_pid` which is later printed.

The `wait` command waits for the `sox` command (running in the background) to finish.

---

As we discussed in [a previous session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428217/current-time-date-as-a-variable-in-bash-and-stopping-a-program-with-a-script/428223#428223): Double-quote all variable expansions.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the great explanation as well as the solution!

Comment: for:
printf 'sox pid is %d\n' "$sox_pid"

Did you %d to ensure that the PID was inputted as an integer?
Why not use %s?
Just trying to learn, thank you.

Comment: @RecklessLiberty No worries :-)  I used `%d` because I'm assuming that `$sox_pid` is an integer. If it's not an integer (for whatever reason), then the statement will generate an error message that can easily be seen.  You could obviously use `%s` for _everything_, but I personally tend to use more specific format specifiers if I _know_ that the thing I'm printing is of a particular type.

Comment: Error IDing, nice.
The & after the sox is so BASH will create the $sox_pid? and printf?
so sox needs to be in the bg for the rest of the script to work?

Comment: @RecklessLiberty The `&` starts the given command as a background task, which gives control back to the script immediately. The PID of the command is then available in `$!`.  The `printf` is solely for the user, in case they would want to kill the job manually with `kill` so that they know what PID to kill (it's not strictly needed).

Answer (score 1):

use trapping:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this is a trap for ctrl + c 
trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() 
{
  echo "Trap: CTRL+C received, exit"
  exit
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know i could nest commands in a variable's parameters. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

`kill -SIGINT <pid>`
is the usual equivalent to `^C`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine :

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script will do exactly the same job of Ctrl^C for background process
# find the PID of running script

pid=$(ps -ef| grep <scriptname>)

echo ".... PSR Stats collection script PID:"+$pid +"is getting exited abruptly"

# exit the process 
kill -INT $pid
```